# I got request in SQL server as stating below

Tags: sql-server

For example I have table like

```
Id      name    age   
01      Praveen  20 
02      mahesh   40 
03      phani    50
```

I want see output like

```
01,02,03
```

Comment: Do you want string with concatenated list of Id's?

Answer (score 1):

Use `For xml path()` trick to do this. Considering that `ID` is of `integer` type else remove the `convert` function

```
SELECT Stuff((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Id)
              FROM   Yourtable
              FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

use cursor to fetch each id and concatenate them to a string

```
DECLARE cur cursor FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
FOR   
 SELECT id 
FROM tbl
 OPEN cur
DECLARE @x  varchar(10)=''
 DECLARE @d int
 FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @d
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
 BEGIN 
SET @x=@x+convert(varchar(10),@d)+','
FETCH NEXT FROM cur  INTO @d
END
Close  cur 
DEALLOCATE cur
SELECT left(@x,len(@x)-1)
```